# Why inference time is higher importing tensorflow.keras libary than importing keras library?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

The problem is that there is a big diference at inference time loading a network model using `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model`. If I load the model using `keras.models.load_model`, inference is 3x faster than `tensorflow.keras` library.

The model is stored in a .h5 file. There's only one thing that maybe i'm doing "wrong": first I trained and saved the model using `keras` library, but (because of other import conflicts after code evolution) now I'm loading it using `tensorflow.keras`.

Libraries versions are:

```
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
tensorflow-metadata==0.22.0
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also experienced this issue.

This happens when you train with `keras` and load with `tensorflow.keras`.

In order to solve your problem ensure that you are both training and making inference with `tensorflow.keras`

Comment: Any idea why? Because, model seems to be loaded correctly.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that i'm saving and loading whole model, but, what if i try to save and load only weights?

Comment: Save and load weights does not solves the problem....

Comment: There are a couple of differences between keras and tensorflow.keras, the latter being the way to go as of now and in the future. Yes, normally when you train in another and load in the other you can have some loading problems. And when you don't (like in your case) and once in mine, you get inference time problems, because of some differently implemented operations/things behind the curtains.

Comment: I re trained the network with `tensorflow.keras` but the inference time still is the same, 3x slower than `keras` library.

Comment: In my case it solved the problem, I am sorry it didn't help.